# cassandra query with additional where clause and filter

Tags: cassandra

I am trying to delete from a table in cassandra, I want to delete based on additional where clause which is not part of primary key but I can pass the primary key also. Scenario is I want to delete a record from search table which has the target table id in additional column. Search field is the primary key eg:

Target table:

```
create table user (id text primary key, email text, other_data text)
```

Search table:

```
create table emails(email text primary key, id text)
```

Now I want to delete from emails table, only when an email belong to a specific id. Is it ok if I issue a statement like below:
`delete from emails where email ='a@test.com' and id ='abc'`

This needs allow filtering otherwise it complains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax you're trying to do won't work (having alternate columns in the WHERE condition that are not part of the primary key).

What you can do is the following:

```
delete from emails where email ='a@test.com' if id = 'abc';
```

That will work, but here is a note to pay attention to:

```
Conditional deletions incur a non-negligible performance cost and should be used sparingly.
```

Not sure the volume of your statements, but large volumes may be noticeable.

-Jim